# Ruby splitting a record into multiple records based on contents of a field

Tags: ruby

Record layout contains two fields:

- Requistion
- Test Names

Example record:

R00000001,"4 Calprotectin, 1 Luminex xTAG, 8 H. pylori stool antigen (IgA), 9 Lactoferrin, 3 Anti-gliadin IgA, 10 H. pylori Panel, 6 Fecal Fat, 11 Antibiotic Resistance Panel, 2 C. difficile Tox A/ Tox B, 5 Elastase, 7 Fecal Occult Blood, 12 Shigella"

The current Ruby code snippet that is used in the LIMS (Lab Info Management System) system is this:

```
subj.get_value('Tests').join(', ')
```

What I need to be able to do in the Ruby code snippet is create a new record off each comma-separated value in the second field.

NOTE:

the amount of values in the 'Test Names' field varies from 1 to 20...or more.

There can be 100's of Requistion records

Final result would be:

R00000001,"4 Calprotectin"

R00000001,"1 Luminex xTAG"

R00000001,"8 H. pylori stool antigen (IgA)"

R00000001,"9 Lactoferrin"

R00000001,"3 Anti-gliadin IgA"

R00000001,"10 H. pylori Panel"

R00000001,"6 Fecal Fat"

R00000001,"11 Antibiotic Resistance Panel"

R00000001,"2 C. difficile Tox A/ Tox B"

R00000001,"5 Elastase"

R00000001,"7 Fecal Occult Blood"

R00000001,"12 Shigella"

Answer (score 0):

If your data is a reliable string which you've shown in your example, here's your method:

```
data = subj.get_value('Tests').join(', ') # assuming this gives your string obj.

def split_data(data)
  arr = data.gsub('"','').split(',')
  arr.map {|l| "#{arr[0]} \"#{l.strip}\""}[1..-1]
end

puts split_data(data)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work in this particular application.  I am dealing with a User-defined Field editor where I am able to add snippets of Ruby code.  Some things are implied and that snippet example I gave you basically takes all the tests associated with that particular Requisition and places them in this virtual field derived from the code.  'Tests' is the name of the table in the database.  Also, I am new to Ruby.  I am an IT guy that tweaks on scripts to get what I need.  I have tweaked JavaScript, C#, VBScript, and may others in other sytems quite easily to do something custom.

Comment: What's happening around `subj.get_value('Tests').join(', ')` ???  If you post that I can probably hack this

Comment: As I said, this is from a User-defined field edit in the application.  I assume anything before the line "subj.get_value('Tests').join(', ')" is implied from behind the GUI.  I ran your updated code, and I didn't error out this time. I got was this (showing partial record since I ran out of room in this comment box):  R00000001,["4 Calprotectin \"1 Luminex xTAG\"", "4 Calprotectin \"8 H. pylori stool antigen (IgA)\"", "4 Calprotectin \"9 Lactoferrin\"", "4 Calprotectin \"3 Anti-gliadin IgA\"", "4 Calprotectin \"10 H. pylori Panel\"", "4 Calprotectin \"6 Fecal Fat\"", "4 Calprotectin \"...

Comment: So does the code work for you?  It does what you've asked.  Beyond that, it becomes impossible for me to help you.  If you need a place to paste stuff https://pastebin.com/

Comment: You mention "create a record" but we have no idea how to create a record because we don't even know how to communicate to the database. What is the backend?

Comment: Your post is dangerously close to being flagged because it is no longer a ruby question and therefore unanswerable.

Comment: this is the first question I have ever posted.  If I am going to flagged, I guess I will just say thank you and apologize for wasting your time.  Cheers!

Comment: I gave it one last try, but we just have no idea how and when this user-defined interface executes the ruby code.  The code I've provide operates on the input data and outputs a string of data formatted exactly as you've requested.

Comment: this gave me an empty result in the Tests Names field.  I think I just do not have enough info to have help me.  You have been more than gracious in trying to help me, and I thank you for that.